# numberOfRowsInSection if (section) error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to use the if (section) method in my numberOfRowsInSection-code. It looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (movies && movies.count) {
            return movies.count;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The first section works like an image, and the second is a json parsed feed called movies. 
But when I launch the app it crashes and gives me this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Can someone explain why?

**EDIT**

cellForRowAtIndexPath-code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *Identifier1 = @"TableHeaderView";
        // cell type 1
        TableHeaderView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier1];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableHeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (TableHeaderView *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        //set the image on the cell

        return cell;
    } else {

        static NSString *Identifier2 = @"PostsObject";
        // cell type 2
        PostsObject *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier2];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PostsObject" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (PostsObject *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        NSDictionary *movie = [self.movies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *strText = [movie objectForKey:[self getTextKey]];

        CGRect rect = cell.title.frame;
        rect.size.height = [self getHeightForText:strText];
        cell.title.frame = rect;
        cell.title.text = strText;
        cell.arrow.center = CGPointMake(cell.arrow.frame.origin.x, rect.origin.y + rect.size.height/2);
        cell.published.text = [movie objectForKey:[self getPostedTime]];
        cell.twitterName.text = [movie objectForKey:[self getTwitterName]];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code.

Comment: Side note - You don't need the 2nd `if` block. Just do `return movies.count;`. That will return 0 if `movies` is `nil`.

Comment: Maybe the array is empty??

Comment: And maybe you should look at the exception traceback to see where the exception occurred??

Comment: It looks okay relative to the movie array.  Can you set an exception breakpoint:  breakpoints tab, plus sign in lower left corner.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like this line is causing the issue:

```
cell = (PostsObject *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

(and the one just like it above it). I'm willing to bet that your NIB is empty. Make sure you have the correct name for it.

Comment: Nope, the NIB is now empty and it's the correct name for it. The app seems to crash on the line return 2; in the numberOfSectionsInTableView method

Comment: Ah. In that case, could you show the code behind `//set the image on the cell`?

Comment: Well, it's strange. Because if I only write return movies.count; in the numberOfRowsInSection-function, it returns all the items from the json and it also returns the image from TableHeaderView with the same amount. So it's something wrong with numberOfRowsInSection...